# Assigning output columns from multiple lines to distinct variables?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

Below you find output of my awk and sed commands that I use to extract 2  lines output from an xml file. I have to assign the host-names and port-names to 4 distinct variables so I can use these to do further inquires.  Can you assist?

cat file | awk | sed produces two lines below

```
Address host1  port_1  Address
BackupAddress host2 port_2  BackupAddress
```

Desired output

```
hosta="host1"
porta="port_1"
hostb="host2"
portb="port_2"
```

I would appreciate and welcome a detailed  explanation with your resolution.

Comment: Show us the file **before** you do `cat file | awk | sed` as that's not a good starting point for anything. Also clarify if you want those for 4 lines to be output or if you want some kind of output which will then allow you to do those 4 assignments to shell variables.

Comment: post a fragment of `cat file` at start

Answer (score 0):

Use awk:

```
awk '
  /^Address/       { print "hosta=\""$2"\"\nporta=\""$3"\"" }
  /^BackupAddress/ { print "hostb=\""$2"\"\nportb=\""$3"\"" }' file
```

or, use a variable to hold the double quote to reduce clutter:

```
awk -v q='"' '
  /^Address/       { print "hosta="q$2q"\nporta="q$3q }
  /^BackupAddress/ { print "hostb="q$2q"\nportb="q$3q }' file
```

I am not sure what code you are using currently.  If you have already written it in awk, you could probably incorporate the above logic there as well.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply - But this does not produce the results I eed.

Comment: It only prints the lines, but I cannot use the outcome as variables. I find the command useful but it does not do what I need.  I assume the print command just prints and does not set the variable.

Comment: You can use `eval` -- `eval $(awk ... file)` to set the variables.